# Are conditions without ISNULL stinky?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, isnull

I come across an article describing different situation in which the SQL code is probably not correct. However, there is one [point](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#not-handling-null-values-in-nullable-columns) which is surprising to me. They claim

> it is wise to explicitly handle NULLs in nullable columns, by using COALESCE to provide a default value

`ISNULL` is mentioned as well. They also reference this [MSDN web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193267%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) giving an example with `ISNULL`. The basic idea here is that it is better to use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE ISNULL([c2],0) > 2;
```

then

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE [c2] > 2;
```

However, the first variant will not be SARG, whereas, the result is not influenced by `ISNULL` at all. I understand the need to handle `NULL` using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in the output, however, I always try to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to handle `NULL` in the predicate. Do I miss something? What is the point of the MSDN issue?

**EDIT:** in order to react on the discussion and mainly on this [post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlyse-with-pankaj-manek/2015/08/20/isnull-around-the-predicate-and-sargability/) I have prepared a simple test

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.LogTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE dbo.LogTable

 SELECT TOP 100000 DATEADD(day, ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530 ), 0) datesent ,
      CASE WHEN ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 ) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 ) END ivalue
 INTO [LogTable]
 FROM    sys.sysobjects
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns

 CREATE INDEX ix_logtable_ivalue ON LogTable(ivalue asc) INCLUDE(datesent);

 -- Q1
 select * from logtable where isnull(ivalue, 0) > 998

 -- Q2
 select * from logtable where ivalue > 998
```

However, the `ivalue` in  Q1 is not SARG. Is there any catch? How should I make the attribute SARG for this particular data and query?

Comment: You are correct.  Don't put in unnecessary `NULL` checks, because that can impede the use of indexes.  I strongly recommend `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`.  Those are the ANSI standard constructs.

Comment: The fact that that example is coming from something that purports to detect bad database code for improvement is very worrisome. You *do* need to think about what could happen when you compare values that can be `NULL`, but reflexively putting `ISNULL` everywhere is downright wrong.

Comment: `What is the point of the MSDN issue`? Dunno :-) The remark from the [original source](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#not-handling-null-values-in-nullable-columns) makes sense whilst calculating things, but the given example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172133(v=vs.100).aspx) is completely mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `isnull` check in the example you provided is pointless. `null > 2` returns `null`, which is not "true", and thus these rows will be excluded from the query anyway. To boot, using `isnull` in that fashion will prohibit the optimizer from using the index on `c2` if you have one.

In short - this sounds like poor advice.

Comment: "null > 2 returns null" - nope, this comparison returns unknown. A bit pedantic but nulls are confusing. The point is still correct - there is no reason to check for null.

Comment: @SMor: very pedantic, since the boolean data type exists only virtually in T-SQL. If it existed in actuality (I wish, it would be quite useful), it's almost certain that the `UNKNOWN`  outcome would be represented by `NULL`. I'm not sure how `NULL` would be "more confusing" than `UNKNOWN`, though, since that's what the thing is there for in the first place.

Comment: `using isnull in that fashion will prohibit the optimizer from using the index on c2 if you have one` is not quite right as may still be issued an `index scan`, as [Pankaj Manek brightly shows us here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlyse-with-pankaj-manek/2015/08/20/isnull-around-the-predicate-and-sargability/). The statement holds true for `index seek`.